# .Net Maui Date and Time pickers do not fire the Focused event

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am in the process of converting our Xamarin project to .Net Maui. On an entry form I have Pickers, Editors, Entries a Date Picker and a Time Picker. When the user taps, or otherwise navigates to an entry control I fire off it's Focused event and when it leaves a control I fire off the Unfocused event for the mere purpose of highlighting the control that the user is focused on. The problem I am having is that when the user taps a Date or Time Picker in Maui the Focused() event does not fire, leaving the highlight on the previous control (Entry, Editor & etc). The picker otherwise works as expected. In the Xamarin app the focused event works as expected, it does not in Maui. Below is the xaml and C# code I am using. It is the same in both Xamarin and Maui, minus the Xamarin.Forms. reference in the Maui app.
Xaml Code:

```xml
<Grid
    Padding="10,0,10,0"
    ColumnDefinitions="150,200"
    RowDefinitions="40">
    <Label
        Margin="15,0,0,0"
        Style="{StaticResource LabelEntry}"
        Text="End Date" />
    <DatePicker
        x:Name="endDatePicker"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        Date="{Binding BeginDate}"
        DateSelected="endDatePicker_DateSelected"
        Focused="DatePickerHighlight"
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        Unfocused="DatePickerHighlight"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>

<Grid
    Padding="10,0,10,0"
    ColumnDefinitions="150,200"
    RowDefinitions="40">
    <Label
        Margin="15,0,0,0"
        Style="{StaticResource LabelEntry}"
        Text="End Time" />
    <TimePicker
        x:Name="endTimePicker"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        Focused="TimePickerHighlight"
        Format="HH:mm"
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        Time="{Binding BeginDate}"
        Unfocused="TimePickerHighlight"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
private void DatePickerHighlight(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var myentry = sender as Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker;
    var myGrid = myentry.Parent as Xamarin.Forms.Grid;
    if (e.IsFocused)
    {
        myGrid.BackgroundColor = App.HighlightColor;

    }
    else
        myGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
}
private void TimePickerHighlight(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var myentry = sender as Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker;
    var myGrid = myentry.Parent as Xamarin.Forms.Grid;
    if (e.IsFocused)
    {
        myGrid.BackgroundColor = App.HighlightColor;

    }
    else
        myGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
}
```

Is this a Maui bug? Am I missing a reference not required in Xamarin? or something else? Thanks.

Comment: How would   `var myentry = sender as Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker;` work in Maui? in Maui it should be `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DatePicker`

Comment: @FreakyAli In my post I make reference to that "It is the same in both Xamarin and Maui, minus the Xamarin.Forms. reference in the Maui app. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunaly this [Pull Request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/8913) seems to have broken Date/Time Picker and it is resolved in .Net 8, if I am not misstaken. Read about it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12899) and also a workaround using Handlers. Also [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8946)

Comment: Thanks. I can wait till .Net 8 as our conversion won't be ready till the first of the year anyway. It seems as though .Net 8 is supposed to solve a lot of Maui ills. Let's hope so.